# Gradle: programmatically specifying compiler options for compileJava task

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, build, annotation-processing

I have a gradle script with a `compileJava` task, and I want it to provide two different `Jar` tasks, `jar` and `jarForce`. The `jarForce` task should compile the sources with `-Awarns` option added so that the annotation processor errors are treated as warnings, and the `jar` task should run compile with the default arguments so that the compilation fails if there are any annotation processor errors. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following, which modifies the options to `compileJava` in the case where `jarForce` is in the task graph:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->
    if (taskGraph.hasTask(jarForce)) {
        println "TRACER jarForce detected"

        // we use verbose simply to illustrate that the options are changed
        compileJava.options.compilerArgs << "-verbose"
        compileJava.options.compilerArgs << "-Awarns"
    }
}

task jarForce(dependsOn: 'jar') {
    doFirst {
        println "TRACER jarForce"
    }
}
```

If you execute `gradle clean jar` versus `gradle clean jarForce`, you'll see the output is quite different, since we use `-verbose` as an illustration. The use of `-Awarns` is left to the reader.

Comment: When is the "-Awarns" option added to compilerArgs? Between the configuration and execution phases?

Comment: re: when? Yes, per this doc, the taskGraph is populated after the project is evaluated (and before a task is executed) - https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/execution/TaskExecutionGraph.html